# PFObject Subclass Getters and Setters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a simple `PFObject` subclass setup. `MyPFSubclass`. It looks something like this:

```
@interface MyPFSubclass: PFObject <PFSubclassing>

+ (NSString *)parseClassName;

@property (retain) NSString *myString;

@end

#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation MyPFSubclass

@dynamic myString;

+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
return @”MyPFSubclass”;
}
@end
```

This works great, as expected, until what I discovered today.

I can set the `myString` value and read and write as expected, an `NSLog` shows the data to be what I set it to.

```
MyPFSubclass *obj = [MyPFSubclass new];

obj.myString = "@hello";
//prints expected value as set above
NSLog(@"%@", obj.myString);

obj[@"myString"] = "@hello";
//prints expected value as set above, again
NSLog(@"%@", obj[@"myString"]);
```

However, if I do the following, I do not get the changed result.

```
obj[@"myString"] = @"Hello";
//prints original value, not as set above
NSLog(@"%@", obj.myString);
```

It seems the key name setters and getters are independent to the subclass setters and getters. I don't want this!

As an example, I have a subclassed view that takes a generic `PFObject` and key name from which it can get and set values.

How can I resolve this? Any reason why I cannot mix usage of the subclass and keyname getters and setters?

Comment: With "key name setters and getters" you mean keyed subscripting?

Comment: See my answer. Not sure its a perfect solution, but certainly not a bad one.

Comment: KVC (`-valueForKey:` et al.) is a similar, but different technique than keyed subscripting. However, in many cases you can replace one with the other.

Comment: Ahh this is where I may have been confused. Thanks for pointing out the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer, however it is a solution.

I found that in the scenario of using a `PFObject` subclass, using `setValue:forKeyPath` is more reliable than using Parse's own bracketing syntax. i.e. `myObject[@"myAttribute"]`.

Where this latter appears non-interchangeable with subclass properties, I found replacing it with `setValue:forKeyPath` works.